# How can I deal with the java.net.ConnectException in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I was trying to copy some local file to the HDFS, with this script:

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/home/czy/IdeaProjects/HadoopInAction/FirstHadoop/src/main/resources/crossView.txt' /user/czy
```

It came like this:

```
copyFromLocal: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

But when I used a script like this(without hdfs://localhost/), it worked well:

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal '/home/czy/IdeaProjects/HadoopInAction/FirstHadoop/src/main/resources/crossView.txt' /user/czy
```

Why did this happen? Why do I received `to localhost:8020 failed` when I configured namenode port to 9000?

Comment: Check if name node process is running or not using sudo jps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your core-site.xml file for valid parameters, server and port names

Check below link..it might be useful...

https://datashine.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-for-more-details-see-httpwiki-apache-orghadoopconnectionrefused/